# Constructing a new variable in R using Case when

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, case-when

Trying to construct a new variable, size class. Size class would be based on employment using the following structure

```
     Sizeclass        Employment Range
         1                    1-9
         2                    10-99
         3                    100-499
         4                    500-999
```

Here is a sample data set

```
      acct        Employment
        1             4
        2             12
        3             1
        4             54
        5             234
        6             13
        7             654
        8             101
```

As of yet, this is the code that I am trying to use

```
            sizeclass %>%
            select(uiacct, naics, employment) %>%
            mutate(sizeclass = case_when (employment >=1 and employment <9 ~ "1",)
            employment >=10 and employment<=99 ~ "2"))
```

Searched the internet but found very little that combined Case_when, mutate, and inequalities. I know that the inequalities are not set up correct. My primary question is if this is the correct structure for creating this new variable?

NOTE: all three answers worked. Quite amazing how helpful this site is when it comes to R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
df <- data.frame(
  acct = c(1:8),
  employment = c(4,12,1,54,234,13,654,101)
)

df <-  setDT(df)

df <- df[,`:=`(
  Sizeclass = case_when(
    Employment >= 1 & Employment <= 9 ~ 1,
    Employment >= 10 & Employment <= 99 ~ 2,
    Employment >= 100 & Employment <= 499 ~ 3,
    Employment >= 500 & Employment <= 999 ~ 4
  )
)]
```

In case you dataset is a 'dataframe' then first convert it to 'datatable'

Comment: I assume that the df item is the data frame?

Comment: your_df would the dataset you have, then convert it to a datatable with 'setDT()'

Answer (score 2):

I like to use `between()` for two-way inequalities to give tidier code:

```
library(tidyverse)

sizeclass %>%
     select(uiacct, naics, employment) %>%
     mutate(sizeclass = case_when(between(employment, 1, 9) ~ 1,
                                  between(employment, 10, 99) ~ 2,
                                  between(employment, 100, 499) ~ 3,
                                  between(employment, 500, 999) ~ 4))
```

Note, if you put the `sizeclass` values in quotes `""` you'll get a character-type column. If you want a numeric column just use the number.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` answer.

```
sizeclass <- data.frame(
  acct = c(1:8),
  employment = c(4,12,1,54,234,13,654,101)
)

library(tidyverse)

df <- sizeclass %>%
  # select(uiacct, naics, employment) %>%
  mutate(sizeclass = case_when(
    employment %in% c(1:9) ~ "1",
    employment %in% c(10:99) ~ "2",
    employment %in% c(100:499) ~ "3",
    employment %in% c(500:999) ~ "4"))
```

Output:

```
  acct employment sizeclass
1    1          4         1
2    2         12         2
3    3          1         1
4    4         54         2
5    5        234         3
6    6         13         2
7    7        654         4
8    8        101         3
```